# method return type based on the condition

Tags: java, spring

I have a method which does various database oprations using spring Jpa.

```
public Employee find(int empId) {

Employee emp = employeeDao.findOne(empId):

if(emp == null)
    return "Records doesnot exists for this Id";
else
   return emp;


}
```

In the above code, there can be various string messages exists for sharing the cause of the error. Since the return type can only be one, so I cannot return both string and Employee object as they are of different types.

I also don't want to use object as return type. What could be the recommended way to use in this type of situation.

Comment: I would return null or Optional and move the message to another layer.

Comment: How is someone calling `find` supposed to make use of the return value if they can't tell what type it is going to be? They would end up having to assign it to an `Object` variable anyway.

Comment: @khelwood, it would either return the object with data or null. Using objects as return type could be dangerous as per various suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. +1 for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having error message details inside your entities is a **BIG NO**. Don't do that.

Use Exceptions wisely.

```
public Employee find(int empId) {

Employee emp = employeeDao.findOne(empId):

if(emp == null){

  throw new EntityNotFoundException("Employee does not exists for this Id");

} else if (emp !=null && emp.getDetails() ==null){

    throw new EntityNotFoundException("Employee Records does not exists for this Id");


} else return emp;

}
```

This is how typical DAO methods do.

If you are constrained to not to use exceptions, have a generic `Object` which shuttles.

```
public class GenericEntityResponse {

public Entity response;
public List<Entity> responses;
public String errorMessage; 
//other common things   

}
```

Use this as a response to all your DAO methods. But I suggest the first way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Throw an exception with the appropiate message if Employee doesn't exist

Comment: @StefanBeike Imho, exception doesn't make a use-case invalid

Comment: Thanks for the response. @Stefan , return null will not specify the error message on why error encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You could return `Optional<Employee>` from your `DAO` method and then in service, if `Optional` is not present, throw Exception with message of your choice.

Example:

```
Employee employee = employeDAO.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException("Employee not present in the DB"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to return a `String` when the `Employee` is not found. What would the caller of the method do with that `String`?

Throw an exception instead:

```
public Employee find(int empId) throws Exception
{
    Employee emp = employeeDao.findOne(empId):

    if(emp == null) {
         throw new Exception("Records doesnot exists for this Id");
    }

    return emp;
}
```

You might want to use some custom sub-class of `Exception`.

You can throw different `Exception` types for different reasons, or the same `Exception` type with different messages.

Comment: Actually it is a rest service where after getting the error string from the mentioned method I am passing the same to the User interface as json.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava create a custom exception class that extends `RuntimeException` and annotate it with `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "No user with such ID")` and throw that exception

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following ways:

**Option 1:**

Throw exception (e.g. `EntityNotFoundException`) with your message incase its `null`

```
public Employee find(int empId) {
  Employee emp = employeeDao.findOne(empId):
  if(emp == null)
     throw new EntityNotFoundException("Records doesn't exists for this Id");
  else
     return emp;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Return the null and handle the message part in the caller function.

```
  public Employee find(int empId) {
     return employeeDao.findOne(empId):
  }

  public String callerMethod(){
     String msg = "Record Exist";
     if(Objects.isNull(find(3))){
        msg = "Records doesn't exists for this Id";
     }
     return msg; 
  }
```

**OPTION 3:** (Close to your requirement)

Create an new EmployeeResponse Class consisting of Employee and ErrorMessage.

```
@Data
public class EmployeeResponse{
   private Employee employee;
   private String error;
}

public EmployeeResponse find(int empId) {
   EmployeeResponse response = new EmployeeResponse
   Employee emp = employeeDao.findOne(empId):
   if(emp == null)
      response.setError("Records doesn't exists for this Id");
   else
      response.setEmployee(emp);

   return emp;
}
```

**PS** - Ideal approach is Option 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not check for nulls because Spring JPA has defined this return type and leave it to consuming classes to handle this.
Moreover if your handling this at DAO layer then its not a good design practice.